# how to display multiple data with ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to display multiple data in my view, the data depend on other data. For example i wanted to display a parent group name then its child groups then again a next parent then its child. I am confused how to do that. I am using ajax calls for that but it don't produced the results that i want.

```
   $.ajax({
        url:'group/fetchparentgroups',
        type:'get',
        success:function(data,status){     //data is a json array object 
                                           //containing all the parent groups
        for(key in data){
            console.log(data[key].name);
            ajaxFetchChildGroups(data[key].id,function(output){ 
            console.log(output) });
        }
        }});

        //the following function take a parent group id as parameter and 
        //return an array containing all the child of that particular parent

    function ajaxFetchChildGroups(parent_group_id,handleData){
    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf- 
        token"]').attr('content') },
        url:'group/fetchchildgroups',
        type:'post',
        data:{'id':parent_group_id},
        success:function(data,status){  
        handleData(data); 
        }});
    }
```

**The output of the code is**

-first parent group name

-second parent group name

-child of first parent

-child of first parent

**But it should be**

-first parent group name

-child of first parent

-second parent group name

-child of second parent

what is the problem in that code. Or recommend another technique to do that i f i directly load the view from controller by sending data to view then how i create such data in controller as child depend on their parent, it means i must iterate through parent to get child.

Should i make a custom class for that having two properties parent and an array containing child of that parent  and i return an array of the objects of that custom class to view.

Comment: are you using eloquent relations ?

Comment: no i am not using relations.

Comment: well i think it would be the best if you use them .. it would lead you to one request caters all .. parents with their corresponding children ..

Comment: suppose i wanted to display some posts with comments and views on that post, i am thinking of making separate requests for posts, comments ad views on them.
I wanted to ask should eloquent relations will also help me in that case?

Comment: yes .. one request will give you list of posts with their corresponding comments

Comment: On the above problem both parent and child belong to same table...so eloquent relations will help in that case...can we make a relation of a table with itself?

Answer (score 0):

you should add async to ajaxFetchChildGroups

```
function ajaxFetchChildGroups(parent_group_id,handleData){
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    url:'group/fetchchildgroups',
    type:'post',
    data:{'id':parent_group_id},
    async:false,
    success:function(data,status){  
    handleData(data); 
    }});
}
```

Comment: So you just mean that the whole data will be load as @habib needed with just async?

Comment: No i don't want to make a synchronus request.

Comment: @dsraj yes i want to make async. Request